# ngtable custom filter of $index instead of filtering from dataset

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

```
  <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'text'}">{{$index}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'number'}">{{row.age}}</td> 
          <td data-title="'Money'">{{row.money}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Country'" filter="{ country: 'select'}" filter-data="demo.countries">{{row.country}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I have `{{$index}}` to print out the index number. I understand that i can filter easily using filter=`{age: 'number'}` however i cannot do the same for `$index` as it is not part of the dataset from the JS.

I want to be able to filter `$index` via a input box instead of automatically filtering upon loading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can filter on $index. But you can simply extend you dataset before rendering the table.

**Controller**

```
$scope.data = [{
    name: 'greg',
    age:29,
    money: 100.10
}, {
    name: 'bob',
    age:30,
    money: 250.00
}];

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
    $scope.data[i].index = i;
}

$scope.table = new NgTableParams({ }, {
    dataset: $scope.data
});
```

**View:**

```
<table ng-table="table" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td data-title="'Index'" filter="{index: 'number'}">{{row.index}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'text'}">{{row.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'number'}">{{row.age}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Money'" filter="{money: 'number'}">{{row.money}}</td>
    </tr> </table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I spent 2 days on this. your solution is neat and clean. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!